# Flow of Logic vs. Flow of Control

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have a series of statements on Sequence Diagrams, and don't know which is false:

**Sequence Diagrams:**

- Sequence Diagrams consistent of a sequence of messages flowing from one object to another
- Sequence Diagrams are a type of interaction diagram that emphasise the time ordering of messages
- Sequence Diagrams are used to visualise the order of messages in a   system
- Sequence Diagrams show the flow of control from one activity to another

From my understanding the flow of control is to do with decisions, loops and  the sequence. What is the difference between the flow of control and flow of logic? Or are these the same?

Answer (score 1):

Important point is what is controlled. In Sequence Diagram, it is *entity (object)* and *message*.

Then, you may easily see the top three statements are for Sequence Diagram because they all talk about *message*.

As the last statement says `control from one activity to another`, it is not talking about control of either of them. Rather it mentions *activity*, so that this is an explanation of Activity Diagram.

Comment: Almost. The last bullet is simply wrong by mixing activities into a SD where you have not direct knowledge about activities.

Comment: sorry, my answer might have been confusing and misleading. What I meant in my answer was that the statement at the last bullet is wrong, and what I tried to say was that if we replace "Sequence Diagrams" with "Activity Diagrams" in the sentence, it'll make sense; `Activity Diagrams show the flow of control from one activity to another`. In some books and web sites, Activity Diagrams are explained like this.

Comment: I think the bullets are from some kind of test where you have to put check marks against the right ones :-)

Comment: yeah, I remember there was a question like this in a test when I was in a college (^o^;